# Portable WF application

Tags: c#

Maybe the title is duplicated, but I could not find my answer in  other questions.
I have the Windows Form Application which works with 2 data sets(text files). How can I make it portable? I mean, how can I run the application without copying the data set into the system (if i have it on pen drive or external hardware I enable to run it directly) or if I copy it every where, it works? .
Can I copy the data sets into the same path of  EXE file? `..bin/Debug/`?
How can I change this path to relative path?

```
StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader("c:\\dataset.txt");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're probably looking for relative URIs. Also note that in Microsoft terms, WF stands for Workflow, not winforms.

Comment: Thanks for notification @Magus. May you help me for relative path? I completely confused!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you are asking for, but if you change your code to:

```
StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader("dataset.txt");
```

This will use dataset.txt from the executing directory of the application rather than being hard-coded to your C: drive.

Comment: Thanks @Richard. Must i copy my data sets into the same path of EXE file? ..bin/Debug/

Comment: @user3403967 yes, if you use ("dataset.txt") you need to copy your dataset.txt to the location of your exe

Comment: since when i run it it show an error that " function has stopped working" . function is the name of my program but when i copy the datasets into C drive it works.